# Proportional pinch zoom limit in core plot iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, limit, core-plot

[The question is similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422842/pinch-zoom-limit-in-core-plot-ios)

But in my case I have a proportional zoom. For example, if I use x2 zoom on x axis then y axis has the same x2 zoom. In this case all the graph lines store their angles.

The problem is in the following method:

```
-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:
```

It takes a specific param - xAxis or yAxis (not both) and in my case xAxis has limitations only. So while xAxis zoom is constant (because it has reached its limit) yAxis zoom still may be increased or decreased. It is hard for me to calculate yAxis limitations because xAxis and yAxis mean time and price (have different measurements).

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Could you provide an example? A screenshot (or mockup) of the graph might help.

Comment: It is what I want to achieve: http://www.yaldex.com/games-programming/FILES/08fig24.gif
It is what I actually have:
http://www.vias.org/comp_geometry/img/math_coords_scaling.png

Comment: Don't understand further if you can't understand even that stretching may be along Ox only.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` but it is useless for my case. If it returns `NO` then the label places are persistent.

The second reason I shouldn't use this method is method `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:`. This method is for replacing old labels with new ones but it is called even less often. So I moved all the calculations into it.

Proportional zoom is by default (if there is no code preventing zoom).

And finally I wrote a `BOOL` variable which equals `YES` when the limit on X axis is reached and prevents changing of Y axis values in this state.